# Capybara and remote links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have this link in **records_path** page:

```
link_to "CLICK HERE", edit_record_path(record), remote: true
```

The controller:

```
def edit
  puts request.format # Just to show you part of the issue
end
```

And when clicked, it executes the **edit.js.coffee** and renders a modal for editing the record.

It works great. **The problem I have is with Capybara**.

```
context 'when on records list page' do
  before { visit records_path }

  context 'when clicking on "CLICK HERE"', js: true do
    before { click_link('CLICK HERE') }

    it 'shows the record name' do
      expect(page).to have_content record.name
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test, it raise an error:

> Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link "CLICK HERE"

But if I remove the **js: true** from the context, it works (It executes the edit method on the RecordsController) but the printed format is **html** instead of **js**. I don't even have an *edit.html*, I just have the *edit.js.coffee* and that is the one that should be rendered in the test.

What am I doing wrong? If the link has the **remote: true** prop, and the test has the **js: true** shouldn't be enough for make it work?

Comment: output `page.html` and see what is actually on the page, are there actually records being rendered with the link to click?

Comment: @TomWalpole Yes, records are being rendered, everything works good.

Comment: You can check what's going on with `save_and_open_page` or the capybara_screenshot gem. Also, your Capybara and Capybara-webkit configurations might be relevant.

Comment: If Capybara is saying it can't find the link - then the link either isn't on the page, or isn't visible on the page.  You claim records are being rendered, have you confirmed that in the test or are you just saying it works in dev mode?  Since you say it works without js: true it's possible you're using transactional database tests so no records are actually visible to the app - see https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Answer (score 0):

In your setup you don't actually create a record.  I am assuming this is the cause of your problem.  The edit_record link will  not show up if you do not have records to edit.  I could be wrong but from what you pasted I think this could be the cause.

Comment: There are records, I have created one but didn't added to the example